# How to divide two summed columns from two grouped by queries?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') date, 
    SUM(quantity) total
    FROM request_items
    GROUP BY HOUR( created_at )
```

It generates a report by summing all quantities from an hour.
So I got something like this:

```
2017-04-01 00:00:00 | 10
2017-04-01 01:00:00 | 05
```

And with this I get the requests:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') date, 
    COUNT(id) total
    FROM requests
    GROUP BY HOUR( created_at )
```

The principle is the same, but now I need to now the average amount of items by requests `(count of items/count of requests) grouped by hour and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data.  `SUM(id)` looks really suspicious.

Comment: I had to change a litle the code for the example, indeed was `count(id)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average, then use `AVG()`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as date, 
       AVG(quantity) as avg_quantity
FROM items
GROUP BY DATE(created_at), HOUR( created_at );
```

Note:  You should not be grouping by the hour without the date -- unless you want to combine hours from different days.  That seems unlikely because you are selecting the entire date.